# Delay redirect Page

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question:

I notice that there is a difference between these two codes:

```
function urlLogin()
{
  window.location = "http://crs.local";
}

setTimeout(urlLogin(),5000)
```

If I use this, I am immediately redirected.

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location = "http://crs.local"},5000);
```

But this one, it works as intended. I just want to ask the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no difference, both should be delayed 5 seconds. Are you sure you didn't have `setTimeout(urlLogin(), 5000)`? This seems to be a common mistake.

The correct way is what you had before you "corrected" the question :D : `setTimeout(urlLogin, 5000)`, passing the function and not invoking it.

Comment: It does seem to be the mistake here.

Comment: @Amadan Sorry, its urlLogin() I mistake the type above.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written, it's as if the output of urlLogin is the input to the first parameter of setTimeout. The first parameter should be the function, not the result of the function.

Try this instead :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    urlLogin();
},2000);
```

Comment: Just removing the `()` would have been enough.